# Getting the names of all the columns and number of rows in a data frame with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to list all the columns, and the number of rows in a Pandas data.frame.
For example, suppose that my data frame `df` looks like:

```
    field1   field2
 x    x1        1
 y    y1        4
```

I would like to be able to run:

```
> df.columns()
['field1','field2']
> df.nrows() 
2
```

Is that possible?

Comment: umm, wouldn't len(yourFrame) give you the number of rows?

Comment: Yes, use `df.columns` and `df.shape[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of columns: a Pandas dataframe has a `columns` attribute (it's not a function). To get a regular list of columns as strings:

```
>>> [name for name in df.columns]
['field1','field2']
```

To get number of rows:

```
>>> len(df.index)
2
```

Comment: If I print `df.index`, I'm just getting a list of my index values. As per the example, how can I get x1, y1, z1, etc. in a list?